# Set Up Route to Template - then variable Entry is undefined

Tags: templating, routes, category, plugin-seomatic

I've got a blog listing channel set up where I'm trying to filter entries listed by the entries field `blogAuthors` based on url segment.

`/articles-and-excerpts/` loads the blog fine

added a route

[image]

but when I go to a page like this `/articles-and-excperts/author/john-doe` I see errors until I add this to the template

```
{% if entry is not defined %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries.section('blogListing').one() %}
{% endif %}
```

Then it works correctly. Why doesn't Craft recognize that this is the blogListing channel?

Also even though this works and displays the content SEOmatic doesn't recognize it now either.

Ultimately I need the following to load on this template:

`/articles-and-excerpts/`
`/articles-and-excerpts/author/author.slug`
`/articles-and-excerpts/category/category.slug`
`/articles-and-excerpts/category/category.slug/author/author.slug`

Currently I have categories using a separate template but haven't attempted to add in the author filtering.

Is there a better approach to this? I had started trying to combine url segments and a query string, but got stuck there as well [Filtering entries by category and author channel](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/33006/filtering-entries-by-category-and-author-channel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables like `entry` are only auto-injected for routes that match the Section's **Site Settings** routes:

[image]

If you're using custom routes, they won't match, and you'll need to set `entry` (or whatever) yourself manually. SEOmatic uses the same Craft mechanism for recognizing injected `entry`s (or whatever), so the same applies there. Vide: [Rendering Metadata From Another Route](https://nystudio107.com/blog/tips-for-using-seomatic-effectively#rendering-metadata-from-another-route)

Comment: Andrew - perfect. Thank you. Of course I should've checked your blog before posting here.